# Proof of weak convergence when domain of rv is N

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

I need to show:
If $X_i, i\geq1, X$ are random variables with domain $\mathbb{N}$, then $ X_n \rightarrow X$ weakly iff $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}: P(X_n = i) \rightarrow P(X=i)$.
The direction $\implies$ is easy (choosing f bounded and continuous such that $f(i)=1, f(k)=0 \forall k \neq i$. How can I prove the converse direction? I tried Portemanteau, but it doesn’t work. I’m grateful for a hint.

Comment: Have you seen Scheffe's Lemma?

Comment: Yes, but I unfortunately don’t see how to use it.

Comment: Just try the definition, i.e. try to show $P(a＜X_n≤b)\to P(a<X≤ b)$ for any $a<b$.

Comment: In class , we used the definition of weak convergence with bounded and continuous functions, maybe that’s where my confusion comes from. Is convergence in distribution the same as weak convergence?

Comment: Idea: $ P(X_n \leq x) = \sum_{i=1}^{x} P(X_n=i)  \rightarrow  \sum_{i=1}^{x} P(X=i) $ for all x natural numbers because we have only finite sums?

Comment: I will refer to Chung's A Course in Probability for some equivalent definitions of weak convergence. Your idea is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be a continuous and bounded function, say by $1$ in absolute value for simplicity. We have to show that
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i)\mathbb P(X_n=i)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i)\mathbb P(X=i)$. To do so, we write for a fixed $N$
$$
\left\lvert \sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i)\mathbb P(X_n=i)-\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i)\mathbb P(X=i)\right\rvert \leqslant \left\lvert \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}f(i)\mathbb P(X_n=i)- \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} f(i)\mathbb P(X=i)\right\rvert
+ \left\lvert \sum_{i=N}^\infty f(i)\mathbb P(X_n=i) \right\rvert +\left\lvert  \sum_{i=N}^\infty f(i)\mathbb P(X=i)\right\rvert \\
\leqslant \left\lvert \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}f(i)\mathbb P(X_n=i)- \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} f(i)\mathbb P(X=i)\right\rvert
+  \mathbb P(X_n\geqslant N) + \mathbb P(X\geqslant N)
$$
hence for each fixed $N$,
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\left\lvert \sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i)\mathbb P(X_n=i)-\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i)\mathbb P(X=i)\right\rvert\leqslant \limsup_{n\to \infty}\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant N) + \mathbb P(X\geqslant N).
$$
Moreover, since $\mathbb P(X_n\leqslant N-1)=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\mathbb P(X_n=i)$, we derive that for each fixed $N$,
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant N)=1-\liminf_{n\to \infty}\mathbb P(X_n\leqslant N-1)=1-\mathbb P(X\leqslant N-1)=\mathbb P(X\geqslant N), 
$$
from which we infer that
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\left\lvert \sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i)\mathbb P(X_n=i)-\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i)\mathbb P(X=i)\right\rvert\leqslant 2\mathbb P(X\geqslant N)
$$
and the fact that $N$ is arbitrary gives the result.

Comment: It seems like this uses the definition that convergence in distribution means that $P(X_n\leq x)\to P(X\leq x)$ for continuity $x$ of the distribution of $X$ after saying "for each fixed $N$".

Comment: @INvisibLE I only use the fact that $\mathbb P(X_n=i)$ converges to $\mathbb P(X=i)$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Nice answer.